# Derivative for a softmax-like function

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks

Recently, an improvement to differentiable neural computer was proposed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.10278.pdf) (Improving Differentiable Neural Computers Through Memory masking, De-Allocation, and Link Distribution Sharpness Control)

On page 4 there is an equation (2) that's used as an activation function for a vector $\textbf{d} \in [0,1] $

$$S(\textbf{d}, s)_i=\frac{(\textbf{d}_i)^s}{\sum_j{(\textbf{d}_j)^s}}$$

and where power $s \in [0, \infty)$

Could someone help find its derivative wrt $\textbf{d}_i$ and wrt $s$, for the Machine-Learning community? It's probably similar to the [softmax derivative](https://medium.com/@aerinykim/how-to-implement-the-softmax-derivative-independently-from-any-loss-function-ae6d44363a9d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
\dfrac{d}{d \mathbf{d}_i} S(\textbf{d}, s)_i & =&\dfrac{s}{\mathbf{d}_i} \left(S(\textbf{d}, s)_i - S(\textbf{d}, s)_i^2 \right)
\\
\dfrac{d}{d \mathbf{d}_k} S(\textbf{d}, s)_i & =&-\dfrac{s}{\mathbf{d}_k} S(\textbf{d}, s)_i S(\textbf{d}, s)_k \qquad\text{ for } k \not=i
\\
\dfrac{d}{d s} S(\textbf{d}, s)_i & =& S(\textbf{d}, s)_i\left(\log_e\left(\mathbf{d}_i\right) -\dfrac{\sum_j \mathbf{d}_j^s \log_e\left(\mathbf{d}_j\right)}{\sum_j \mathbf{d}_j^s }  \right) 
\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you! is it possible to get the derivatives only in terms of $S(d,s)$ ? That way, we don't spend RAM memory to store incoming arguments, just the outputs. For example, for sigmoid, such a derivative is $\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))$. Does $log_e$ mean natural logarithm, $ln$?

Comment: $\log_e$ is indeed the natural logarithm.  Since $\frac d{dx} k^x = \log_e(k) k^x$, the derivative with respect to $s$ will inevitably involve logarithms